# How I compare a string of a file, and if it does not exist, I write it in the file in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, file, fwrite

I have this code on my Wordpress Site:

```
//Get day, month and year
$date = getdate();
$day = $date['mday'];
$month = $date['mon'];
$year = $date['year'];

//Create a list
$list = array();

//Open create a file
$myfile = fopen("lista.txt", "r+");

//If true push an ID on a list
if(($day==10)&&($month==4)&&($year==2019)){
    array_push($list,"#borrar22marc");
}

if(($day==10)&&($month==4)&&($year==2019)){
    array_push($list,"#borrar6abril");
}


if(($myfile = fopen("lista.txt", "a+"))) {
            foreach ($list as $value) {
                   fwrite($myfile, $value."\n");
                flush();
                }
        }
```

What I want is to compare a variable with what is inside the file, and if it does not exist in the file, write it

Edit: this is the file right now:

```
#borrar22marc
#borrar6abril
#borrar22marc
#borrar6abril
#borrar22marc
#borrar6abril
```

Comment: What does the text file look like? 1 word per line? Delimited by a delimiter? Only 1 word inside? Do you have a sample?

Comment: exactly, 1 word per line

Comment: so you want to loop through each line and compare a string that contain '#borrar22marc' this type data ??

Comment: I want to loop throught each array value and compare this value with each line of the file